# Does the intersection of VC and CLIQUE belong to NPC?

Tags: np-complete, clique, vertex-cover

Define: $$L=\{(G,k) :  G\text{ has a vertex cover of size at most $k$, and a clique of size at least $k$}\}$$

I need to determine whether $L\in \mathrm{NPC}$ or $L\in \mathrm{P}$. I suspect that $L\in \mathrm{NPC}$, been trying to prove it by looking for a reduction from Vertex Cover, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3):

The graphs with clique size at least $k$ and VC at most $k$ have a particular
structure: They can be partitioned into three sets, $C$, $I$ and a singleton
$\{s\}$; $G[C]$ is a clique, $G[I]$ is an independent set and $s$ is just a
vertex.  $G[C \cup I]$ is what's called a [split
graph](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_39.html).

Proof: If a graph $G$ contains a clique of size $k$, then that clique uses up
(at least) $k-1$ of your vertex cover budget.  Let $G,k$ be a yes instance and
$C$ any $k$-clique.  Observe that $G - C$ is a star with possibly isolated
vertices.

There are two cases: $G-C$ has edges, and $G-C$ does not have edges.  The latter
case is trivial, since we can let $C$ be the solution.  In the former case,
$G-C$ is the star graph with isolates.  Let $s$ be the vertex with non-zero
degree.

Both these cases lead to polynomial recognition algorithm.  The one in which
$G-C$ is an independent set, is the case where $G$ is a split graph.  The other
case has one vertex $s$ for which $G-s$ is a split graph.  Guess $s$, and you're
back at case 1.

As xskxzr pointed out, there is not necessarily a unique "split partition", that is, a partitioning of a split graph into the vertex sets $C$ and $I$, however, there are at most $n$ such partitions, and you can try all.  This leads in the end to an $O(n^3m)$ algorithm for VC∩C, which I'm sure can be improved.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the reduction would be to add a clique of size $k$. but then if I use $k'=2k-1$ I would need a clique of size $2k-1$, and that's a problem.

Comment: I havn't heard of split graphs. Is there a simple polynomial algorithm to determine if a graph is a split graph? and if so, how can I use this information to solve my problem?